# Changing the color of an EditorGUI.ProgressBar?

Tags: colors, progress-bar, unity-game-engine

I want to show a ProgressBar.  I am using this code:

```
EditorGUI.ProgressBar(Rect(3,45,100-6,20),20/700.0, "Armor");
```

I want to change the color of the ProgressBar from a light blue color to a red color. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, it doesn't appear that you can. However, I had a similar issue where I wanted a very customized bar with different colors to denote different things. I ended up using [EditorGUI.DrawPreviewTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.DrawPreviewTexture.html). If you initialize the colors you want to use as a Texture2D, then pass them into that function with the properly placed rectangles, you can create portions of a bar that can change size and location to give the appearance of a standalone progress bar, especially if you keep the positions and size updated in the `Update()` function.